# Sorting on Taxonomy in archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, taxonomy

```
    <?php 
get_header();
?>
<?php

//Define the function

function customize_customtaxonomy_archive_display ( $query ) {
    if (($query->is_main_query()) && (is_tax('employee')))

    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '3' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
}

//Hook the function

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'customize_customtaxonomy_archive_display' );

/**
 * @todo filtering on gov_categorie
 */

?>
<section class="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="split-block sidebar-right">
            <div class="main-content" data-animation="fadeInUpSmall">
                <h1>Garderense Ondernemers Vereniging</h1>
                <?php 
                    $loop = new WP_Query(array(
                        'paged'          => get_query_var('paged'),
                        'post_type'      => 'gov_members',
                        'posts_per_page' => 20,
                        'tax_query'      => array(
                            // Note: tax_query expects an array of arrays!
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'gov_categorie', // my guess
                                'field'    => 'name',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ));
                ?>
                <div class="gov-wrapper">
                    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="gov-block">
                            <a href="<?php echo the_permalink()?>">
                                <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
                                <p>
                                    <?php echo esc_html(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'gov_address', true)); ?><br />
                                    <?php echo esc_html(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'gov_postal_city', true)); ?><br />
                                    <?php echo esc_html(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'gov_phone', true)); ?><br />
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <aside id="sidebar">
                <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    the_terms( $post->ID, 'gov_categorie' ,  ' ' );
                endwhile; ?>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php 
get_footer();
?>
```

With the code above i get none results.

When i delete the tax_query i get all the results how can i change that piece of code to filter on a selected taxonomy.

---

I've changed it but still no results..., I'm trying this with a custom post type and a custom taxonomy. Also i'm doing this within a custom made plugin. so maybe i'm doing something wrong in another file, because when i make a taxonomy-gov_categorie.php the pages won't find it.

Comment: Change order by 'title' to 'post_title'

Comment: Please use comments or edit your question to elaborate. Answers aren't meant for it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify a taxonomy term in tax_query. It should go:

```
'tax_query'      => array(
   array(
    'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name', // my guess
    'field'    => 'name',
    'term'     => 'Term name'
   ),
 ),
```

I prefer using *'field'=>'slug'* in such cases as term names are more likely to be changed.

And also change order by 'title' to 'post_title'as Abhisek mentioned in the comment.